# Python: Help converting messy if-elif statement ladder within loop a into dictionary switch case for creating grpc ssl certificates

Tags: python, json, ssl, grpc, grpc-python

I'm having trouble cleaning up some of my code.

In general terms the python code is meant to read two json files. The first json file includes the addresses for each microservice, the second json file includes a list of the services that each service communicates with. The function of this code is so create grpc ssl certificates for each microservice through looping over these two json files.

I have written the code, but I have used `if` statements and it is very messy, but I am struggling to clean the code up using dictionaries.

Below I will list a sample of the two jsons I have described above:

**ServicesAddresses.json**

```
[
  {
    "service":"service-A",
    "address": ["localhost1"]
  },
  {
    "service":"service-B",
    "address": ["localhost2"]
  },
]
```

**ServicesUsed.json**

```
[
  {
    "service":"service-A",
    "services_used": ["service-B", "service-C"]
  },
  {
    "service":"service-B",
    "services_used": ["service-C", "service-D"]
  },
]
```

I will share the code I use to loop over the first json and assign the addresses to variables below

```
for address in addressData:
    if address["service"] == "service-A":
        addresses.serviceA = address["address"]
    elif address["service"] == "service-B":
        addresses.serviceB = address["address"]
```

Finally I will share the code used to loop over the second json and to generate the ssl certificates using a function called `cert_create` which has an input of the address of each service

```
for service in runningData:
    if service["service"] == "service-A" and service["services_used"] == ["service-B", "service-C"]:
        os.chdir('/certs/service-A/service-B')
        cert_create(str(addresses.serviceA))
        os.chdir('/certs/service-A/service-C')
        cert_create(str(addresses.serviceA))

    elif service["service"] == "service-B" and service["services_used"] == ["service-C", "service-D"]:
        os.chdir('/certs/service-B/service-C')
        cert_create(str(addresses.serviceB))
        os.chdir('/certs/service-B/service-D')
        cert_create(str(addresses.serviceB))
```

As you can see, with a large number of services this logic can become quite a monstrosity. The issue is, with my limited experience of python, I don't see how creating a switch statement with dictionaries will be able to simplify this logic while retaining the same number of assignments and functions of a if statement.

Any ideas? I know this is quite basic but I feel as if with a different language such as go or java I would have been able to make this code a lot cleaner

Comment: What is the `addresses` object?

Comment: Added missing quote in the last code block.

Comment: @Jgd It's the name of the class where I store all of the services as empty strings

Comment: Hm, that `addresses` object looks very non-pythonic. Can't it have some dict of services, so you can get them by key?

Comment: @Emil Yes now that you mention it, thanks for fixing the quote on the code block

Comment: I just wonder how this would be done in Java or go are they missing dictionaries and functions? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os

running_data = [
  {
    "service":"service-A",
    "services_used": ["service-B", "service-C"]
  },
  {
    "service":"service-B",
    "services_used": ["service-C", "service-D"]
  },
]

address_data = [
  {
    "service":"service-A",
    "address": ["localhost1"]
  },
  {
    "service":"service-B",
    "address": ["localhost2"]
  },
]

def get_service_address(service):
    return [i.get("address")[0] for i in address_data if i.get("service") == service][0]

for data in running_data:
    service = data.get("service")
    used = data.get("services_used")
    if service is None or used is None:
        raise ValueError("Missing information")
    for u in used:
        print(os.path.join("certs", service, u))
        print(get_service_address(service))
```

of course replace the prints with os.chdir and create_cert

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need some additional data structure (like dict below) or modification of existing `addresses` object so you can get address by name.
Of course, if your addresses data comes from user input consider sanitizing/checking it.

```
services_addresses = {
    'service-A': str(addresses.serviceA),
    'service-B': str(addresses.serviceB),
    'service-C': str(addresses.serviceC),
}

for service in runningData:
    service_name = service["service"]
    for service_name_used in service["services_used"]:
        os.chdir(f'/certs/{service_name}/{service_name_used}')
        # here comes the difference - you need additional dict
        cert_create( services_addresses[service_name] )
        # or modification of addresses object ?..
        # cert_create( addresses.getServiceAddress(service_name) )
```